# [Angular]: Tap on to an observable that has been used in template with async pipe

Tags: angular

I have an observable in an angular component that emits a value in 2 seconds interval. In the template I am printing that observable with `async` pipe and in the component class, I have `piped` a tap operator on to that observable to get updates.

Code:
app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, share, shareReplay, tap } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  obs = new Observable((observer) => {
    let i = 0;
    setInterval(() => {
      observer.next(i++);
    }, 2000);
  })

  ngOnInit() {
    this.obs.pipe(share(),tap((data) => {
      console.log(data); //should print 1,2,3
    }));
  }

}
```

app.component.html

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>{{ obs | async }}</p>
```

But the tap operator is not executing here. As the async operator already subscribes to the observable, what is the way that I can tap on that observable and get updates?

[stackblitz code example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wxxtlx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `pipe` when creating the observable, and instead of `setInterval` there is an `interval`:

```js
obs = interval(2000)
  .pipe(
    // map()
    share(),
    tap((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    }),
  );
```